# Display shifts in curve and slope with Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following MWE and would like to plot three lines on it, displaying the shift in height (and maybe the change in slope) between the second and third lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$\hat{S(4)}$},xlabel={$S{^*}_{breakeven}$},ylabel style={rotate=-90},domain=1:25, legend style={legend pos=north west,font=\scriptsize}, legend cell align=left]
\addplot+[black, mark=none, loosely dashed,forget plot]{x};
\addplot+[samples=200,mark=none]                                                    {exp(0 + 1*ln(x))};
\addplot+[samples=200,mark=none, dotted, thick]             {exp(0.46 + 0.28*ln(x))-1};
\addplot+[samples=200,mark=none, dotted, thick]             {exp(1.66 + 0.28*ln(x))-1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to display lines and arrows to show the shift in the curve, similar to the annotations that have been added to the following image i.e. an annotated bracket (with arrows) for the shift in the curve and an annotated right angle (with arrows) to show the slope?

[image]

Comment: Add for example `coordinate[pos=0.6](a) coordinate[pos=0.8] (b) (a)-| (b)` to any of your addplot commands for right angles.

Comment: Great. How do I place the curly brackets and the b2 annotation?

Comment: Same way with `brace` decoration.